# Sending a score value to a database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, mysqli

Hi so I have a database set up that looks like this https://gyazo.com/240fce43cfcf45f123d64b76acc4093f , however, I don't know how to interact with the score element. To use the ID, Name etc. I followed a youtube tutorial by TechAcademy, where she uses PHP to interact with the database.
In the java file of my android studio project, when a button is clicked and certain conditions are met, a counter increments and the activity is restarted, however I want this counter to be sent straight to my database so the users score increments (Example is user clicks the button and the conditions are met, a 1 will be displayed in the database). My php files are as follows for the User, Name etc if they're any help.

Register.php

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("your_mysql_hostname" , "your_username" , "your_password" , "your_database_name");

    $name = $_POST["Name"];
    $email = $_POST["Email"];
    $username = $_POST["Username"];
    $password = $_POST["Password"];


    $insertquery = mysqli_prepare($con , "INSERT INTO contacts ( Name ,Email,Username,Password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insertquery , "ssss" , $name , $email , $username , $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($insertquery);


    mysqli_stmt_close($insertquery);

    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Fetch User Data.PHP

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("your_mysql_hostname" , "your_username" , "your_password" , "your_database_name");

$password = $_POST["Password"];
$username = $_POST["Username"];

$selectquery = mysqli_prepare($con , "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($selectquery , "ss" , $username , $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($selectquery);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($selectquery);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($selectquery , $ID , $name , $email,$username , $password);

$user = array();

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($selectquery))
{
    $user[name] = $name;
    $user[email] = $email;
    $user[username] = $username;
    $user[password] = $password;
}

echo json_encode($user);

mysqli_stmt_close($selectquery);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have another php script to handle score update. And it will be using MySQL 'Update' statement instead. For example:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("your_mysql_hostname" , "your_username" , "your_password" , "your_database_name");

$username = $_POST["Username"];
$score= $_POST["Score"];


$query = mysqli_prepare($con , "UPDATE contacts SET score=? WHERE username=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, $score, $username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($query);


mysqli_stmt_close($query);

mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

Very rough example. But should show you enough to get started.

Comment: Ok thanks a million. And what kind of things do I need to add to my java file to use this?

Comment: I don't know how you android side looks like. Did you use the android to do the registration (register.php)? If yes, it will be similar which posts the data to the server side. Post the username and score instead.

Comment: Yea I used android to make a registration activity. And ok thanks :)